# sort number strings

Tags: powershell

Read text file data:

```
1,26586,0
1,789,1
1,5689,0
2,5895,-2568
2,5899,5689
2,548679,-11.485
```

and then sort the result:

```
1,789,1
1,5689,0
1,26586,0
2,5895,-2568
2,5899,5689
2,548679,-11.485
```

I have tried `get-content file txt | sort-object -unique`, but the result is:

```
1,26586,0
1,5689,0
1,789,1
2,5899,5689
2,5895,-2568
2,548679,-11.485
```

Comment: -1 for poor problem statement. What's the exact sorting order you are looking for? Column by column?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split the lines into separate fields, so the sorting routine can address each column individually. And since you want to sort numerically, you also need to convert the strings to actual numbers.

Try this:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.txt' -Headers 'A','B','C' |
  select @{n='A';e={[int]$_.A}}, @{n='B';e={[int]$_.B}}, C |
  sort -Unique A, B
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort-Object treats everything as a string.

To achieve what you want, you'll need to either explicitly tell it what parts of the input string to treat as numerical types, or format them into meaningful strings by zeropadding the numbers.

Zero-padded string:

```
$Lines = Get-Content .\file.txt
$Lines |Sort-Object -Unique { "{0:D10}{1:D10}{2:F10}" -f $([int[]]($_-split",")) }
```

Treat as individual numbers:

```
$Lines = Get-Content .\file.txt
$Lines |Sort-Object -Unique {[int]($_-split",")[0]}, {[int]($_-split",")[1]}, {[double]($_-split",")[2]}
```